# XAML - want to change seachbox's search icon color

Tags: c#, xaml

this is my search box tag & I want to change his icon color to black from purple(Default color)

```
<SearchBox Height="50" Width="800" Margin="0,0,0,0" ></SearchBox>
```

[image]I am Begineer in Xaml

Comment: Where does the <SearchBox> control come from?  I don't know of one in built-in WPF.

Comment: yes yes the one in built-in wpf

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using a Universal Windows Application in Visual Studio, select your text box in the design viewer and right-click to open the menu.  In the menu, select 'Edit Template' and 'Edit a Copy.'  This will give you the option to select parts of your search box like the button to edit the background.  Find this code in the generated `App.xaml` code to get started:

```
<Button x:Name="SearchButton" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Background="#FFB49494" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="{ThemeResource SearchBoxButtonThemeFontWeight}" Style="{StaticResource SearchButtonStyle}"/>
```

Comment: it is not working, i mean it shows the color are changing but when i launch app it show again default color

<Button x:Name="SearchButton" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="{ThemeResource SearchBoxButtonThemeFontWeight}" Style="{StaticResource SearchButtonStyle}"/>

Comment: You want to use a custom color in the 'Background="transparent"' category rather than 'transparent'.  Right now it's transparent according to the code you sent me.  What is the XAML you used to make it purple?

Comment: well basically I used this code
<SearchBox Height="50" Width="800" Margin="0,0,0,0" ></SearchBox>
purple color is his default color

Comment: The default color is actually transparent as in your first comment, so some other code either in your application or in your templates are overriding the default template color, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the UI editor, right click on the control and select "Edit template" and "Edit copy". Now place the style code where you want, put *Style="{StaticResource YourStyleName}"* in your XAML code of the SearchBox and change the following section in your style. There are different "VisualStates" here. The state for "PointOver" already exists. Here you can either change the value for i. e "SearchBoxButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush" directly or create a new brush to overrride the property. for the "normal" state, the StoryBoard entry must be copied and adapted.

I recommend to create a SolidColorBrush to override the ThemeResource.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SearchBoxButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Gray"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SearchBoxButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush" Color="White"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SearchBoxButtonBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="White"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SearchBoxButtonForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Black"/>
```

**Before:**

```
<Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Grid Background="Transparent">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>                  
                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SearchGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SearchBoxButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SearchButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SearchBoxButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
```

**After:**

```
<Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Grid Background="Transparent">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SearchGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SearchBoxButtonForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SearchButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SearchBoxButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SearchGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SearchBoxButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SearchButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SearchBoxButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
```